# Do any states or countries punish people less for distracted/drunk driving accidents compared to speeding accidents?

Tags: policy, law

Have any countries or states implemented a policy similar to this?

> People who cause non-fatal accidents due to distracted driving (texting, eating, make up, sleeping, etc.) or drugged driving (drunk or DUI) should have *lesser* punishments compared to people who committed a non-fatal accident due to speeding.

I'm genuinely trying to do research and see if the merits/issues of said proposal, I'm not trying to push my opinions on the topic. This is what I wanted to research:

- Have any countries/states implemented a similar policy?
- What would the merits of such a proposal be?
- What would the harms of such a proposal be?

Please include sources so I can read more if need be.

Comment: The proposal seems unclear.  Please provide an example, or hypothetical example, of what legally might happen with a distracted driving accident with such a policy *vs.* without.

Comment: You have to consider that speeding - defined as exceeding posted limits, not "too fast for conditions - is a) something done by almost everyone, at least in the US, and b) not really a significant cause of accidents.

Comment: Proposal seems stupid: non-fatal accident is non fatal in both cases, but DUI is more dangerous then simply speeding, because DUI often includes speeding and/or other violations.

Comment: Wouldn't DUI/Distracted driving lead to more accidents than simply speeding?

Comment: How it is about governments/politics????

Comment: I didn't know this exchange was a research assistant...

Comment: I have to agree with rs.29.  when I'm on the highway *everyone* is going at least 10 miles over the speed limit, so everyone is guilty of speeding.  However, given the nature of the high way this adds far less risk of an accident occurring then distracted driving, DUI, or just tailgaiting.  So punishing someone more severely for speeding, which everyone is doing, rather then engaging in the activities which are far more likely to be the root cause of an accident, seems counter productive.

Comment: It seems like the justification could be that speeding is a purely voluntary act by someone who is presumably of sound mind. When you're drunk you're mentally impaired, so less culpable for making the poor decision of driving in that condition.

Comment: This question appears to be pushing for a narrative that DUI/Distracted driving should be punished less harshly based on comments on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell (having checked) no countries have implemented this or a similar policy.

The closest I can see is various policies on drunk driving, which are intended to punish more harshly those causing accidents as a result of driving under the influence.  The general result of these policies has been a reduction in drunk driving.

The general system is to categorise driving offences into "careless" and "reckless" categories.  Speeding could be in either category, depending on the context.

A simple rule which categorises offences as "speeding" or "non-speeding" would immediately create some strange situations:

- Jack is driving slightly over the speed limit (as he confessed at the scene of crime) when he swerved to avoid an animal, and collided with another car.  The speed was a minor contributory factor to the crash.  This would therefore be harshly punished
- Jill was drunk and driving erratically when she drove down wrong way on a motorway. She wasn't speeding (in fact her speed was about 30mph, the wrong way) A serious accident resulted, luckily nobody died.  This would be treated mildly
- Jo was playing "chicken" against random other vehicles on a country road with a speed limit of 60mph.  They probably were speeding (but not by much, and not at the actual time of the crash), but it is impossible to prove. The crash resulted in severe life changing injuries. This would be treated mildly.

The general effect of introducing laws is to change behaviour. But very few accidents are wholly the result of speeding: and it is very hard to prove speeding, except in extreme cases.  So the probable result is very few harsh punishments being applied.

One reason that we can have a specific offence of drunk driving is that is is possible to test for drunkenness after the fact.

Comment: Another key point is at times speeding can be unintentional DUI is always intentional and the same could probably be said about distracted driving

Comment: @JoeW While DUI may be intentional, one might argue that a drunk person doesn't have the *mens rea*

Comment: @Barmar Being drunk is never an excuse for poor acts and in most cases it is punished severely. If the law was more lenient on someone because they were under the influence of alcohol/drugs it would become an easy excuse to get out of trouble.

Comment: @JoeW That's true as the law currently exists, but diminished capacity is often a mitigating factor in other situations, so one could argue that this is an unfair law. The difference, of course, is that someone chooses to become drunk in the first place (even alcoholics are not excused from this, as many laws related to drunkenness predate recognition of this as a disorder, and society in general attaches a stigma).

Comment: @Barmar Drinking/Drugs are deliberate choice to make so having diminished due for those reasons is purely a personal choice which is why the penalty for that is generally harsher than something that you can't control.

Comment: @JoeW Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @Barmar No you seem to be saying that because they are under the influence that is an excuse for their actions when I am saying that the law does not see it that way and typically increases the penalties.

Comment: @JoeW I said "The difference, of course, is that someone chooses to become drunkk in the first place".